# While loop only running once even though it worked fine earlier

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a function that i call so i can add names to a list. I want to keep adding names to the list unless i enter 'end' or 'End'. I am using a While loop that is set to True to do this and use if/else statements to append the list. However, when i run my code it only runs the While loop once before it leaves it. I have a similar function doing the same thing except with numbers instead of names and that works no problem.
I was using this earlier and it worked no problems but i can't see what has changed to make the While loop not work.

```py
Student_Names=[]                                                                                                                                                                         
def names():                                                                                          
    student_name=str(input("Please enter the students name and type when complete: "))                
    Student_Names.append(student_name)
    while True:                                                                                       
        student_name=str(input("Please enter the students name and type when complete: "))            
        if student_name ==('end') or ('End'):
            break
        else:
            Student_Names.append(student_name) 
names()
```

Any help is seriously appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```py
Student_Names=[]                                                                                                                                                                         
def names():                                                              
    student_name=str(input("Please   
    enter the students name and type when complete: "))                
    Student_Names.append(student_name)
    while True:                                                                                       
        student_name=str(input("Please     
        enter the students name and 
        type when complete: "))            
        if student_name =="end" or student_name=="End":
            break
        else:
            Student_Names.append(student_name) 
names()
```

Change the if statement it worked.

Comment: Live saver, thank you so much. Have a great evening